# OS X app doesn't launch new window on dock icon press in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, window

I am making a Mac app in Swift, and running into a problem. When my app is first launched from the terminated state, it automatically launches a new window. But if the user `X`s out of my app (with the red X icon) instead of quitting it, then hits the app icon of my app, a new window doesn't automatically open.

How can I make my Mac app launch a new window every time the dock icon is hit, as long as there isn't already a window of my app open?

Comment: reep! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814921/how-do-you-make-the-application-window-open-when-the-dock-icon-is-clicked

Comment: @johnelemans Thanks but arggg objective c :]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953139/how-to-handle-applicationshouldhandlereopen-in-a-non-document-based-storyboard-a

Comment: @johnelemans Thanks for your help! I translated that second one into Swift and posted answer for myself :D.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this to your App Delegate:

```
func applicationShouldHandleReopen(theApplication: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {
    if !flag {
        for window: AnyObject in theApplication.windows {
            window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to put

```
lazy var windows = NSWindow()
```

to somewhere at AppDelegate

and then implement

```
func applicationShouldHandleReopen(theApplication: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {
        if !flag {
        for window: AnyObject in theApplication.windows {
            window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Like @Owlswipe wrote

Comment: Can you explain why the windows var is needed?